# nodejs - parsing chunked twitter json

Tags: json, twitter, node.js

The nodejs server 'gets' this JSON stream from Twitter and sends it to the client:

```
stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=gadget
```

The data returned to the client is 'chunked' JSON and both JSON.parse(chunk) and eval('(' + chunk + ')') on the client side result in parsing errors. 
Concatenating the chucked pieces and waiting for the 'end' event isn't a solution either

I noticed previous samples used something like this on the client side that apparently worked before:

```
  socket.onmessage = function(chunk) { 
  data = eval("(" + chunk.data + ")");
  alert(data.user.screen_name);
```

I'm using this on the client side and it results in a parsing error:

```
var socket = new io.Socket();
    socket.on('message', function(chunk) { 
    var data = eval('(' + chunk + ')'); // parsing error
    alert(data.screen_name):
```

I know that its successfully returning a JSON chunk with:

```
  var socket = new io.Socket();
        socket.on('message', function(chunk) {  
        alert(chunk): // shows a JSON chunk
```

Server:

```
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    client.each(function(e) {
      e.send(chunk);  
  });
```

Did something change or what else em I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** The 'end' event does not fire because its streaming?

```
http.get({
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
  host: 'stream.twitter.com',
  path: '/1/statuses/filter.json?track...
}, function(res) {

  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    client.each(function(e) {
      e.send(chunk);  
  });  
 });

  // does not fire
  res.on('end', function () {

  });  

...
```

I'm looking into the difference with http 1.0 and http 1.1 as far as sending chunked data.

Comment: are you sure concatening the chunks and waiting for the end event doesn't work? I think that's the way it should be done as it can't parse the half-chunk received.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look at the section titled [Parsing Responses](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/processing#Parsing_responses) in Twitter's documentation.

> Parsing JSON responses from the Streaming API is simple every object is returned on its own line, and ends with a carriage return. Newline characters (\n) may occur in object elements (the text element of a status object, for example), but carriage returns (\r) should not.

On the server side, keep accumulating chunks until you see the carriage return `"\r"`. Once the carriage return is found, extract the string up to the carriage return, and that gives us one tweet.

```
var message = ""; // variable that collects chunks
var tweetSeparator = "\r";

res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    message += chunk;

    var tweetSeparatorIndex = message.indexOf(tweetSeparator);
    var didFindTweet = tweetSeparatorIndex != -1;

    if (didFindTweet) {
        var tweet = message.slice(0, tweetSeparatorIndex);
        clients.forEach(function(client) {
            client.send(tweet);
        });
        message = message.slice(tweetSeparatorIndex + 1);
    }
});
```

The client becomes simple. Simply parse the socket message as JSON in its entirety.

```
socket.on('message', function(data) {
    var tweet = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Comment: I think it should be message.split("\r").forEach(function(tweet)

Answer (score 2):

@Anurag I'cant add comments, however instead of

```
if (chunk.substr("-1") == "\r")
```

it should be:

```
if ( chunk.charCodeAt(chunk.length-2) == 13 )
```

The carriage return isn't the last character.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. I have changed my implementation a bit. Twitter's chunks aren't always ending in a newline or carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend piping the response into a JSON parser. You can use this: https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream