# Is there a (JSON or XML) stream parser for nodejs?

Tags: parsing, node.js

is there a parser for nodejs that can be connected to a a stream of chunked JSON (or XML) data and will emit events similar to how the built in JSON parser does?

The stream I am about to parse is coming from an HTTP request to a backend server for example. No special formatting can be assumed for the incoming JSON. IOW, the solution in [nodejs - parsing chunked twitter json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771914/nodejs-parsing-chunked-twitter-json) won't work for me.

Jan

Comment: Just a comment, since I don't have any concrete answers, but there are several XML pull parsers that use various methods to parse stream data, and some Google searches on "JSON pull parser" and similar return some promising looking results--mostly in Java and C-based languages, though.

Comment: http://oboejs.com/ parses JSON in a streaming manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question, but I have used [node-xml](https://github.com/robrighter/node-xml) before with streamed, chunked data. There are indeed events which are fired. [sax-js](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js) seems more recently active, but I cannot comment on that project.

I cannot comment on an equivalent JSON parser.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for node-xml has the parseString method to be handed one chunk after another.

Answer (score 2):

- [node-xml-splitter](https://github.com/lindory-project/node-xml-splitter) could be an answer concerning your xml
  streaming needs
- [jsonpars](https://github.com/creationix/jsonparse) could be an answer concerning your json
  streaming needs

Answer (score -4):

For json, you may use the following snippet.

coffeescript

```
make_parser = (callback)->

    state_parse=0
    level=0
    buffer=0

    parse_out = (data)-> 
        m = data.match /[{}"]/
        if m?
            c = m[0]
            buffer += data[..m.index]
            remaining = data[m.index+1..]
            if c == "}"
                level -= 1
                if level == 0
                    callback JSON.parse(buffer)
                    init_state()
            else if c == "{"
                level += 1
            else if c == '"'
                state_parse = parse_string
            state_parse remaining
        else
            buffer += data

    parse_string = (data)->
        m = data.match /["\\]/
        if m?
            c = m[0]
            buffer += data[..m.index]
            remaining = data[m.index+1..]
            transition =
                '\\': parse_special
                '\"': parse_out
            state_parse = transition[c]
            state_parse remaining
        else 
            buffer += data

    parse_special = (data)->
        if data.length > 0
            buffer += data[0]
            state_parse = parse_string
            state_parse data[1..]

    init_state =->
        state_parse = parse_out
        level = 0
        buffer = ""

    init_state()

    (data)->
        state_parse data




fs = require "fs"
s = fs.createReadStream "somefile.json"
s.setEncoding 'utf8'
s.on "data", make_parser (d)->
    console.log "-----"
    console.log d
```

javascript:

var fs, make_parser, s;

```
make_parser = function(callback) {
  var buffer, init_state, level, parse_out, parse_special, parse_string, state_parse;
  state_parse = 0;
  level = 0;
  buffer = 0;
  parse_out = function(data) {
    var c, m, remaining;
    m = data.match(/[{}"]/);
    if (m != null) {
      c = m[0];
      buffer += data.slice(0, m.index + 1 || 9e9);
      remaining = data.slice(m.index + 1);
      if (c === "}") {
        level -= 1;
        if (level === 0) {
          callback(JSON.parse(buffer));
          init_state();
        }
      } else if (c === "{") {
        level += 1;
      } else if (c === '"') {
        state_parse = parse_string;
      }
      return state_parse(remaining);
    } else {
      return buffer += data;
    }
  };
  parse_string = function(data) {
    var c, m, remaining, transition;
    m = data.match(/["\\]/);
    if (m != null) {
      c = m[0];
      buffer += data.slice(0, m.index + 1 || 9e9);
      remaining = data.slice(m.index + 1);
      transition = {
        '\\': parse_special,
        '\"': parse_out
      };
      state_parse = transition[c];
      return state_parse(remaining);
    } else {
      return buffer += data;
    }
  };
  parse_special = function(data) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
      buffer += data[0];
      state_parse = parse_string;
      return state_parse(data.slice(1));
    }
  };
  init_state = function() {
    state_parse = parse_out;
    level = 0;
    return buffer = "";
  };
  init_state();
  return function(data) {
    return state_parse(data);
  };
};

fs = require("fs");

s = fs.createReadStream("somefile.json");

s.setEncoding('utf8');

s.on("data", make_parser(function(d) {
  console.log("-----");
  return console.log(d);
}));
```